Searching for multiple strings in Curl and Grep
So, I have this if/else condition which checks for a certain string in curl output.
If the output has either "yahoo" or "google", then I want it to hit the if block, otherwise hit the else block.
I used -q to search for yahoo. But I am not sure how to add two conditions [that is one string as "yahoo" and the other string as "google" in the same curl query]
if curl https://yahoo.com | grep -q "via yahoo"
    echo "via yahoo or hotmail"
else
    echo "not via yahoo or gmail"
fi


See the accepted answer to Match output of a CURL in an IF-ELSE condition in BASH.

Regarding 'one string as "yahoo" and the other string as "google" in the same curl query' especially - it's not clear if you're asking how to curl 2 domains at once or grep for either of 2 strings in the output of a curl command or identify which of multiple curl domain commands produced output or something else. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do.

When I run curl https://yahoo.com I just get the output redirect and when I run curl https://google.com I get output including The document has moved, neither of which outputs via ... so I'm thinking you don't really want to parse the curl output in the way you show. Please provide sample input and expected output that would clarify your needs and we can copy/paste test with.

Extending OP's current code to match on multiple strings:
if curl https://yahoo.com | grep -Eq 'via (google|yahoo)'
then
    echo "via google or yahoo"
else
    echo "via neither"
fi

NOTE: grep -Eq 'via google|via yahoo' would also work
